# Paperweights used to hold down Art, Posters, or Maps for framing

Tags: tool-identification

My local frame shop uses weighted leather discs to lay prints out flat.

These paper weights are essential for keeping rolled posters flat on a table. I can also see them being used in the map / cartography hobby. They're soft, so as not to damage the paper, small enough to cover only the corners, but also heavy enough to hold down a rolled poster and not move.

I'd like to buy some for framing at home, but I'm finding these items to be surprisingly difficult to find. I can find almost no pictures of them in use. The ones I can find seem overly expensive or rare.

What are these items called in the framing world?

Where do frame shops purchase these paper weights? Are they available at craft stores?

[image: using 4 weighted leather paper weights to lay flat a rolled poster]

I might describe them as paper weights, bean bags, sand bags, shot bags, weighted leather disks, etc. But there are not many results for any of these terms. It seems like these should be a common item.

Comment: In the sewing world there are similar items in use to hold down pattern pieces while cutting the fabric according to the pattern. They are generally called "pattern weights" and you can easily make your own by covering any suitable object like metal scraps, washers or even stones with a soft fabric. Here's just [one example](https://so-sew-easy.com/make-sewing-pattern-weights-11-ways/)

Comment: called [weight bags](https://www.engineersupply.com/drawing-weight-bags.aspx) on a drafting supply site.

Answer (score 1):

**Weight bags/pattern weights** as pkamb and Elmy said in the commments, or simply **paper weights**, potentially with additional qualifier terms for the material or other characteristics, as rebusB suggested.  Also, I searched the phrase "paperweights to hold down art" and the ones you're looking for are there.  There is a wide range of variations available, or you can make them yourself.